# Get multiple Tesseract PSM and file formats at once

Tags: php, tesseract

Is it possible to get multiple PSM modes from Tesseract, and the plain text and HOCR format, at once?

I am currently running Tesseract 3 times on each document: Once to get the orientation info (PSM 0), once to get the formatted text (PSM 3) and once to get the HOCR formatted result. This makes it take 3 times as long.

Is there a better way to get this info from Tesseract without OCRing the document multiple times?

I am using this [PHP Tesseract wrapper.](https://github.com/ddeboer/tesseract)

```
$tess = new Tesseract();
$textor = $tess->recognize(storage_path("image.jpg"), null, 0);
$textplain = $tess->recognize(storage_path("image.jpg"), null, 3);
....
```

Answer (score 1):

`tesseract` doesn't support to run multiple `PSM` modes and output formats in one execution.

If performance is a concern, you may try [multi-threading in PHP](http://www.smddzcy.com/2016/01/tutorial-multi-threading-in-php7-pthreads/) to run multiple tesseract at the same time for your use case.